# Microsoft Edge Extension tab content

Tags: javascript, browser, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

I am exploring a bit on Microsoft Edge extension development. Basically I am trying to read HTML content of a tab. Below is code snippet from my solution.

My manifest.json looks likes below

```
{
    "name" : "HTML Reader",
    "version" : "1.0.0.0",
    "author" : "Stack Memory",
    "browser_action" : 
    {
        "default_icon" : 
        {
            "20" : "icon_20.png",
            "40" : "icon_40.png"
        },
        "default_title" : "Sample extension",
        "default_popup" : "index.html"
    },
    "content_scripts" : [{
            "js" : ["js/index.js"],
            "matches" : ["*://*/*"]
        }
    ],

    "content_security_policy" : "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'",
    "default_locale" : "en",
    "description" : "This is a sample extension that illustrates the JSON manifest schema",

    "permissions" : 
    [
        "*://*/*", "notifications", "cookies", "tabs", "storage", "contextMenus", "background"
    ],
    "icons" : {
        "128" : "icon_128.png",
        "16" : "icon_16.png",
        "48" : "icon_48.png"
    },
    "minimum_edge_version" : "33.14281.1000.0",
    "web_accessible_resources" : ["icon_48.png"]
}
```

My `index.js` looks like below

```
function getDomObject(tab) {
    browser.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {
        method: 'getDomContent'
    },function(response) {
        if (browser.runtime.lastError) {
            console.log("Error: ", browser.runtime.lastError);
        } else {
            alert(response.innerText);
        }
    });
}

function onCodeCall(){
    browser.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs){
        var tab = tabs[0];
        getDomObject(tab);
    });
}
```

Function `onCodeCall` runs on click of extension button.

I am not getting any error and also my callback function does not hit. This code works fine in Chrome but just fails in Edge.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide a simple sample, including `manifest.json`, `background.js` and `content.js`? And you're calling above method in `background.js`, right?

Answer (score 2):

`tabs.sendMessage` can only be called in extension context, such as background page. However, you are calling it in content scripts, which obviously won't work, no matter in Microsoft Edge or Chrome.