# Microsoft Edge Console error on pasting a variable while debugging

Tags: javascript, browser, microsoft-edge

This may be a basic problem but its getting on my nerves now. I was exploring Microsoft Edge. While debugging, I am pasting a variable in console tab to explore its value and below is the error ('SecurityError') that I see.

[image]

I could see the value in watch and all that's not I am looking for. I want to go to console tab to run some functions on the object tp explore more on that part.
Its just annoying. I am unable to get through it. Could anyone help here?
Thanks.

Comment: Ensure you're accessing these variables in extension page, like options page, background page or popup page

Comment: I am trying to access these variables in index.js. I think both should be same.

Answer (score 2):

`browser.tabs` can only be accessed in extension context, such as background page. However, you're calling it in content scripts (I know it from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39320175/microsoft-edge-extension-tab-content)), which obviously will get nothing.